# I'm getting a 'str' and 'int' TypeError on my bitwise program when using 'input'

Tags: python, string, integer, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

This simple program checks if the 4th bit in a user provided integer is turned on. You provide a number (say 12, for example) and then it will be converted from a string to an integer, then from base10 to binary. However, despite the `int()` and `bin()` conversions I'm still getting an error saying that `&` can't be used on 'str' and 'int'.

As far as I understand the `int()` and `bin()` functions, the user provided number should be a bitwise integer when it's passed to the `check_bit4()` function. What am I missing?

```
def check_bit4(x):
    check = 0b00001000
    if x & check > 0:
        return("on")
    else:
        return("off")

x = bin(int(input("Enter Integer ")))
check_bit4(x)
```

```
  File "Problem3.py", line 3, in check_bit4
    if x & check > 0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: `bin(..)` converts the int back to a string (with `'0'`s and `'1'`s).

Comment: All numbers are stored in binary format internally (at the lowest level), thus bitwise operations, e.g. `&` can be directly performed on `int`s without converting in any way.

Answer (score 4):

There is **no reason to use `bin(..)`**. `bin(..)` does **not convert an integer to a binary equivalent**, an int is already stored binary. It constructs a **representation** (something a *person* can read) of the integer with 0s and 1s as a string. Indeed:

```
>>> type(bin(1425))
<class 'str'>
```

So you can simply use:

```
x = int(input("Enter Integer "))  # look ma, no bin(..)
check_bit4(x)
```

In your function, you write `0b00001000` but this is also an integer: if you would have written `8` directly, that would not have made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It is because **bin(x)** returns a **string**
 
Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin

Hence in the above line you are trying to **& (and)** string and int which causes the error.
So we need to convert the string to int before using **& (and)** operator. 
Instead of these tedious tasks, I would suggest you to use **& (and)** operator directly on the input number.

```
def check_bit4(x):
    check = 8  #decimal representation of 0b00001000
    if x & check:  #if condition will be true if the answer is non zero
        return("on")
    else:
        return("off")

x = int(input("Enter Integer "))
print(check_bit4(x))
```

I hope this solves your issue :)